# How to add Big Oh expressions?

Tags: java, big-o

Sorry for the super basic question! I have the following methods and need to determine the run time analysis in terms of n. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffDUK.png)

For the above problems, I determined the following expressions:
1A. O(1)+O(n)+O(n^2) = O(n^2)
1B. O(1)+O(n)+O(25) = O(n)
To find the final answer, do I just follow the largest order of magnitude? And does this look correct to the picture?

Comment: in a word: yes.

Comment: By "largest order of magnitude", note it can be deceiving: `O(n log n)` vs `O(n ^ 2)` might not be immediately apparent (unless you see tricks like dividing `n` on both sides, and seeing `O(log n) < O(n)`). A consistent approach is the limit law: for functions `f(n)` and `g(n)`: take `lim (n->inf) of (f/g) = z`. If `z=inf`, then `O(f) > O(g)`. If `z=0`, then `O(f) < O(g)`. Otherwise, `O(f) = O(g)` (with scaling factors).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to calculating Time Complexity is to understand how the algorithm works and count the operations. The way you approached the time complexity for the above-mentioned problems is correct.

If you still have any confusion, refer to this blog from Medium
https://medium.com/dataseries/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-with-big-o-notation-9afe33aa4c46

Comment: Note that answer should not typically just be a link to an external resource (particularly a news article): Essential parts/information should be contained within the answer itself, less the link becomes dead in the future.